# I have facing a double login issue in my php application?

Tags: php, session, authentication, double, admin

i login to my dashboard form front end of my php application through login popup but the problem is when i enter my login credential first time it will not redirected to me my dash bored  it will redirect to my front end page but i login again with the same credential or other valid credential of different user of dashboard it will login to dashboard .

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{

    //for super admin login detials
    $username = cleanstr_header($_POST['username']);
    $password = cleanstr_header($_POST['password']);
    $adminresu = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and password=md5('".$password."')");
    if(mysql_num_rows($adminresu) > 0)
    {
        $adminrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($adminresu);

                    //start super admin login 
        if(isset($adminrow['id']))
        {
            unset($adminrow['password']);
            $_SESSION['Auth'] = $adminrow;

            if($_SESSION['Auth']['role'] == 'admin')
            {
                //MENU MANAGEMENT SECTION
                $query_privileges = mysql_query("select * from privileges where user_id='".$adminrow ['id']."'");
                @$row_privileges = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_privileges);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges'] = $row_privileges;
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_grandParent_menu'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_grandParent_menu']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_parent_menu'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_parent_menu']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_sub_menu'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_sub_menu']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_footer_menu'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['menu_footer_menu']);

                //NEWS MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['news_add_news'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['news_add_news']);

                //TENDER MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['tender_add_tender'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['tender_add_tender']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['tender_expired_tender'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['tender_expired_tender']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['tender_application_tender'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['tender_application_tender']);

                //GALLARY MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['gallery_photo_gallery'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['gallery_photo_gallery']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['gallery_video_gallery'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['gallery_video_gallery']);

                //SLIDER MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['slider_header_slider'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['slider_header_slider']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['slider_promotional_slider'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['slider_promotional_slider']);

                //DIGNITARIES MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['dignitaries_statutory'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['dignitaries_statutory']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['dignitaries_registrar'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['dignitaries_registrar']);

                               //DEAPARTMENT MANAGEMENT SECTION
                                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['add_links'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['add_links']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['add_departments'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['add_departments']);

                //USER SECTION
                //USER MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['user_add_user'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['user_add_user']);

                //PRIVILEGES MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['privileges_assing_privileges'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['privileges_assing_privileges']);


                //BCUD SECTION
                //LINK ACTIVATION MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_link_activation'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_link_activation']);

                //LETTERS MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_letters'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_letters']);

                //SUBJECTS MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_study'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_study']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_faculty'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_faculty']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_course'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_course']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_group'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_group']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_subject'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_subject']);

                //DISTRICT MANAGEMENT SECTION
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_district'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_district']);
                @$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_talukas'] = explode(', ',$_SESSION['Auth']['privileges']['bcud_talukas']);

            }
             echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="admin/admin/index.php";</script>';
             exit;
        }
   }
   //start college login
   elseif(mysql_num_rows($adminresu) == 0)
   {
    //for college login detials
    $colgresu = mysql_query("select * from college_login where username='$username' and password=md5('".$password."')");
    $colgrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($colgresu);
    if(mysql_num_rows($colgresu)>0)
    {
        if(isset($colgrow['id']) and $colgrow['role'] == 'college_member')
        {
            unset($colgrow['password']);
            $_SESSION['Auth'] = $colgrow;
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="admin/user_admin/index.php";</script>';
            exit; 
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        $loginError= "The email or password you entered is incorrect."; 
    }
}
//  }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors if you remove the error suppression '@'?

Comment: first remove error suppression then you may fin what you are missing